# Word count on SharePoint List

Tags: json, list, sharepoint

very new to ShatePoint lists,

I have a sharepoint list that I want to add a word count to in a multi line text box?

Any ideas?

Comment: What SharePoint version do you use?If you are using SharePoint online, currenlty there is no such way to meet your requirement, If you are using SharePoint server, please refer to this article to set Character Count for Multi-line Text box in SharePoint List Forms:  https://kavitamishra.wordpress.com/2016/12/25/character-count-for-multi-line-text-box-in-sharepoint-list-forms/

Comment: It's online, thanks for your help

Comment: As said above, in SharePoint online, we cannot add a word count in a multi line text box.